# Make an async multiple update in a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, async-await

I have an array of elements to insert in a database. For each of them, I have to check their integrity (I send "Bad request" if I don't find an element):

```
  let ret = []
  const { idElement, type, description, name }  = req.body
  let promises = []
  req.body.pjs.forEach((pj) => {
    promises.push(new Promise (async function(resolve, reject) {
      const { rows } = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM files WHERE uuid = '${pj.uuid}' AND name = '${pj.name}'`)
      if (rows.length == 0) { res.status(400).send("Bad request!") }
      const idFile = rows[0].id
      await db.query(`UPDATE elements
        SET base = base || '{"type":"file","valeur":"${idFile}","description":"${description}","name":"${pj.name}"}'::json
        WHERE id = ${idElement}; `)
      resolve({id: idElement, name: pj.name, val: idFile, description: description})
    }))
  });


  (async function() {
    const asyncFunctions = promises
    await asyncFunctions.reduce(async (previousPromise, nextAsyncFunction) => {
      await previousPromise;
      const r = await nextAsyncFunction();
      ret.push(r)

    }, Promise.resolve());
  })();


  res.send(ret)
```

I took the example of the paragraph "3) one-by-one" heree: https://dev.to/afifsohaili/dealing-with-promises-in-an-array-with-async-await-5d7g

This trick works for a lot of use cases in other parts of my code, but not for this particular case. I have this error:

```
          const r = await nextAsyncFunction();
                         
TypeError: nextAsyncFunction is not a function
```

And I don't know why. If anybody could give me a hand, it would be very kind :)

Comment: Have you tried a `for .. of` loop? `for (let pj of req.body.pjs) { await things }`

Comment: I didn't, but I'll keep that in mind, sometimes I just do useless complicated things... The explanations from traktor53 helped me solve my problem. Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is correct, the second parameter of `reduce` is the next entry of the array being reduced, which in this case is the `promises` array.

So the immediate solution is to `await` the promise without trying to call it:

```
const r = await nextAsyncFunction;  // no () on the end
```

Why the `nextAsyncFunction` name was used instead of `nextPromise` or variation thereof is not self evident - it's certainly confusing and led to errors.

Aside from that there seems to be some bugs waiting to happen:

- If the `"Bad request"` message is sent, the code continues to execute and tries to update the database and resolve the promise pushed by the `forEach` function. Subsequently `res.send(ret)` will (is likely to?) error as an attempt to send a second set of response headers. Try thowing a `Bad Request` error and catching it in a promise `catch` handler to send the `400` response.
- there is no attempt to wait for asynchronous processing to finish before executing

  ```
    res.send(ret)
  ```

  which would send an empty array if it succeeded.

The `reduce(async (previousPromise, nextPromise)` construct is a rather complicated way of waiting for promises to be resolved in turn by using `for ... of` :

```
(async function() {
   for( promise of promises) {
       ret.push( await promise);
   }
}()
.then( ()=> res.send(ret));
.catch( ()=> // server error response?
```

Handling requests that are a mixture of valid and invalid `pj` request values may require further attention.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
You're right about the fact that I'll need further attention to handle some specific cases, it's on my roadmap, but I first wanted to understand why the problem occurred, and your explanations are very comprehensive.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @djcaesar9114 I found the use case of waiting for promises to fulfill in the order they were created, as shown in the linked blog, is a bit manufactured and when only the result of all promises is of interest  [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would be a better and more standard choice. Happy coding.